# CM10 on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 n8010 missing things

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note, s-note

I installed CyanogenMod 10 on my WiFi Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1. However, some things are missing.

First of all, I want the S-Pen handwrite keyboard, as well as the S-Note app.
Also, if possible make peel work (very unlikely, but just in case anyone had make that work)

I tried to install these from an unzipped stock ROM but (as expected) it didn't work. Do I have to install any library? If yes, which?

BTW: Please do not recommend other ROMs. I want CM. Maybe alternative apps.
If I find the libraries and APKs, I may create a flashable zip.

Comment: "make peel work" What's peel?

Comment: the remote control program. (n8000 & n8010 have infrared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These apps won't work with custom ROM's, as they are designed to be run with the Samsung software, and require libraries etc from the Samsung software.

Comment: any alternative apps?

Comment: @ttouch AFAIK, the s-pen doesn't work with CM10, or any custom ROMs because it requires specific drivers that Samsung has not released source for.

Comment: can I find the required libs and do it manually?

Comment: @ttouch The Samsung libs are closed source, and they will only work on Samsung ROMS.

Comment: Is it a coding problem or a license problem?

Comment: License, also the fact that Samsung have not released the source.